# Ordinal regression or Spearman rho

Tags: regression, ordinal-data, spearman-rho

I am a complete beginner in statistics and I am confuse which method is more appropriate. I have two variables;  The independent variable is continuous ( hours)  while my dependent variable is ordinal (high motivation, moderate motivation, low motivation).  I am confuse whether to use  spearman rho or ordinal logistic regression.

Which method is better? Are there more appropriate methods other than these?

Thank you and any kind of advice is highly appreciated.